# subdomain forwarding to VMs, EC2, etc (with or without IPs)

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, virtual-machines

let's say I own a domain: `example.com` .  I want to have different users have their own subdomains, and I may want to move these around to different hosts.  I may also not trust these users greatly.  (userA may have chosen a duplicate password that may be hacked into, so I don't want A to share the same host with B.)  I would love a config file like

```
userA.example.com local-vm /var/vmware/userA.vmx
userB.example.com amazon-ec2 someip
userC.example.com IP 164.67.167.211
userD.example.com local-vm /var/vmware/userB.vmx
```

and the DNS domain `example.com` (the domain) then forwards requests to its subdomains appropriately.  the requests could be web, ssh, sftp, etc.  I can put `example.com` onto bare metal.

one problem that arises is that my limited number of IP addresses means that /var/vmware/userA won't have their own IP address---`example.com` needs to pass requests (not only URL but also some other ports like ssh) onto a virtual machine that it hosts.

and I want sub-sub-domains be controlled by the same VM:  that is, it would send another.userC.example.com also to 164.67.167.211 .

I think the solution will entail running my own DNS server on the main domain.  each subdomain gets its own "A" record.  (I think A records can also point to IP's that are elsewhere, such as on amazon ec2.)  in addition, I need to provide bridge access to the virtual machines hosted on the metal, and indicate in the A records that particular vm's are requested.  somehow.  am I investigating the right approach?  how have others solved this problem?

sincerely,

/iaw

Comment: It's not apparent what you are asking for.  I get that you want to create 4  separate VMs - each one for 4 different users (UserA-D).  It starts to get blurry from here - do you want each VM to run a DNS server hosting a subdomain (UserC.example.com for example) that only UserC manages? Or would you be happy with using wildcards in the example.com zone to point all queries for anything in UserC.domain.com to the same IP address (164.67.167.211).  Hint: the latter is very trivial to do.  The potential shortage of IP addresses might be an issue as well.  Consider separate questions for this.

Comment: the main domain would manage what computer runs the subdomain.  so only the main domain would have to run a DNS server.  the fact that I own only one IP address is indeed a constraint.